# Getting missing dates between max and min dates in pyspark

Tags: sql, function, date, pyspark

Hi I have a column with dates out of that I need to generate missing values between max and min dates with distinct dates excluding max and min dates in the answer in pyspark?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [sequence](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/sequence.html) and furthermore can be exploded into intermediate rows as sequence returns a list

#### Data Preparation

```py
s = StringIO("""
id,min_date,max_date
abc,2022-07-01,2022-07-15
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn('min_date'
                            ,F.to_date(F.col('min_date')                   
                                ,'yyyy-MM-dd'
                            )
             ).withColumn('max_date'
                            ,F.to_date(F.col('max_date')                   
                                ,'yyyy-MM-dd'
                            )
             )

sparkDF.show()

+---+----------+----------+
| id|  min_date|  max_date|
+---+----------+----------+
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|
+---+----------+----------+
```

#### Sequence and Explode

```py
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('missing_dates',F.explode(
                                F.expr("sequence(min_date + 1,max_date - 1,interval 1 day)")
                            )
                        )

sparkDF.show()

+---+----------+----------+-------------+
| id|  min_date|  max_date|missing_dates|
+---+----------+----------+-------------+
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-02|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-03|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-04|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-05|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-06|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-07|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-08|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-09|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-10|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-11|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-12|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-13|
|abc|2022-07-01|2022-07-15|   2022-07-14|
+---+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: This does not help me because In my case there is no missing dates in sequence for ex : min date  2022-07-01 and max date 2022-07-15 and I have dates 07-01, 07-02, 07-03 but not 07-04 and again not 07-07, I need only those missing dates to be generated